# Execute a stored procedure for each row inside a table for each distinct UID

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-cursor

I have a table of with a Unique ID and a set number of columns as seen below. Each row in the table has a UID and then distinct values in each column. The stored procedure takes each of these values (including the UID) and runs a multitude of other code.

To run this it would be:

```
EXEC stored_proc @UID @Col1 @Col2 etc
```

Each UID must run at a different time and each row for said UID needs to be loaded at the same time. Once loaded the script needs to move to the next UID.

The most obvious approach to this is via a cursor but I have had no real progress. I have attempted this via a cursor that uses a temporary table of only the UID and inner joined this for each row but sadly it did not work.

Sample table (actual table: circa 5000 rows):

| UID | Version | Site | QuestionOI | GeneralAnswer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 212109191425-01 | 6 | AGBNL | 4 | GENANSWER1 |
| 212109191425-01 | 6 | AGBNL | 9 | NULL |
| 212109191425-01 | 6 | AGBNL | 100 | NULL |
| 212109191425-01 | 6 | AGBNL | 103 | NULL |
| 212109191425-03 | 6 | AGFCA | 11 | NULL |
| 212109191425-03 | 6 | AGFCA | 22 | NULL |
| 212109191425-05 | 6 | COBAR | 4 | GENANSWER2 |
| 212109191425-05 | 6 | COBAR | 9 | NULL |
| 212109191425-05 | 6 | COBAR | 13 | NULL |
| 212109191425-05 | 6 | COBAR | 15 | NULL |

Can anyone think of an alternative approach/way to iteratively loop through each UID then run a stored procedure on each row for the UID? Use of a cursor is not essential.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and an award will be given for a clean and most importantly quick processing speed (note the nested SP takes little time to run)

Thanks!

*Heres a sample of some code I tried as requested, it seemed to loop through each of the lines rather than UID then row.
The stored procedure would run instead of the second print statement
Note I've had to alter it a bit for sensitivity reasons.*

```
Declare @ClientID VARCHAR;
Declare @UID VARCHAR;

DECLARE Cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT Site FROM #InsertTable

OPEN Cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @ClientID;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Processing ClientID: ' + @ClientID;
    DECLARE Cur2 CURSOR FOR
        SELECT UID FROM #InsertTable Where Site=@ClientID;
    OPEN Cur2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @UID;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Found UID: ' + Cast(@UID as Varchar);
        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur2 INTO @UID;
    END;
    CLOSE Cur2;
    DEALLOCATE Cur2;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur1 INTO @ClientID;
END;
PRINT 'DONE';
CLOSE Cur1;
DEALLOCATE Cur1;
```

Comment: Didn't work how, could you post your code? A cursor would work and is the only way I know of to execute a proc on each row individually. That said, it is not the most optimal approach. What does the procedure do? You might look into whether it could be refactored into something set based, so you don't have to process row by row (slower)

Comment: @SOS The stored procedure has many nested inserts etc and wasn't created by me so I definitely have to use it.

Comment: What to col1, col2 represent? Are they different each time the SP runs?

Comment: @SOS added code similar to what I have tried (there has been many attempts)

Comment: @SteveFord Yes, they are distinct as I detailed above :), each UID has 63 corresponding rows infact. Thanks!

Comment: Yes but what does Col1 represent, if it's Version then call it Version

Comment: `Declare @ClientID VARCHAR;` This is a bad habit. Always specify the length of variable-length datatypes. What you declared is a single character string. Which probably shouldn't be varchar anyways but that's a different issue.

Comment: @SMor yeah you are right that was just used for the example, will make sure to specify the length!

Comment: I would look into using a table valued parameter for this other stored procedure and then refactor that procedure so it can handle and process a whole set instead of a single row.

Answer (score 2):

A cursor would work and is the only way I know of to execute a procedure on *each row* individually. That said, it is not the most optimal approach. A cursor is almost always going to be slower than a set based approach. You might look into whether it could be refactored so you can avoid the cursor and row by row overhead.

```
 DECLARE @YourCursor CURSOR 
    , @UID VARCHAR(50)
    , @Version INT  
    , @Site VARCHAR(10)
    , @QuestionOI INT   
    , @GeneralAnswer VARCHAR(10);

SET @YourCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT [UID]
        , [Version] 
        , [Site] 
        , QuestionOI 
        , GeneralAnswer
    FROM YourTable
    ORDER BY [UID];

OPEN @YourCursor;  

--- load first row           
FETCH NEXT FROM @YourCursor 
INTO @UID, @Version, @Site, @QuestionOI, @GeneralAnswer 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
        --- execute proc 
        EXEC stored_proc @UID, @Version, @Site, other variables...
      
        --- get next row           
        FETCH NEXT FROM @YourCursor 
        INTO @UID, @Version, @Site, @QuestionOI, @GeneralAnswer 
END;  
CLOSE @YourCursor;  
DEALLOCATE @YourCursor;  
GO
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. It is correct this cursor would work in a line by line sense I have had similar to this working. The problem is that additional layer where only one UID can be ran at a time. For example the UID 212109191425-01 must be ran for all rows before moving on to the next UID (constraints in the stored procedure), it then would need to move onto the next UID 212109191425-03

Comment: Yes, the cursor above will execute one UID at a time. I was just mentioning it's usually possible to refactor the logic to do the same thing - but with multiple records at one. I've done that a lot with legacy procedures.

Comment: You probably need to add an ORDER BY UID to the SELECT cursor ensure that all UID records are processed in order and all of the same UIDs are processed at the same time

Comment: @SteveFord - Ah, good catch. I missed that the UID's repeated.  Pandasman - do you just need the UID value for executing the proc - or the other columns too? Does order matter?

Comment: @SOS Yeah it looks like an ORDER BY could stop the repetition. The stored proc uses the UID and all the columns also, the order after the UID doesn't matter so I think that could work.